# How can I open a file and iterate through it, adding data from only certain lines?

Tags: python, parsing, file-io

I have the following code

```
my_file=open("test.stl","r+")
vertices=[]

for line in my_file:
    line=line.strip()
    line=line.split()
    if line.startswith('vertex'):
        vertices.append([[line[1],line[2],line[3]])

print vertices

my_file.close()
```

and right now it gives this error:

```
  File "convert.py", line 10
    vertices.append([[line[1],line[2],line[3]])
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My file has a bunch of lines in it, alot of them formated as vertex 5.6354345 3.34344 7.345345 for example (stl file). I want to add those three numbers to my array so that my array will eventually have [[v1,v2,v3],[v1,v2,v3],....] where all those v's are from the lines. Reading other similar questions it looks like I may need to import sys, but I am not sure why this is.

Comment: Please show us your actual code. This will not print `[]` anywhere; it will raise a `SyntaxError` in the `append` line, and when you fix that, it will raise a `NameError` when you print `verticies`.

Comment: abarnert is correct. If you don't post your actual code, all we can do is guess until the cows come home.

Comment: I have updated the question with the real code and the real output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vertices.append([[line[1],line[2],line[3]])
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Remove the first `[` (there is missing `]` otherwise) to fix the `SyntaxError`. There are other errors in your code.

---

To parse lines that have:

```
vertex 5.6354345 3.34344 7.345345
```

format into a list of 3D points with float coordinates:

```
with open("test.stl") as file:
    vertices = [map(float, line.split()[1:4])
                for line in file
                if line.lstrip().startswith('vertex')]
print vertices
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the lines in your STL file have any leading whitespace?

If they do, you need to strip that off first.

```
    line = line.strip()
```

Also: calling `line.split()` doesn't affect line. It produces a new list, and you're expected to give the new list a name and use it afterwards, like this:

```
    fields = line.split()
    vertices.append([fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]])
```

Comment: Also, `[fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]]` can be compactly written as `fields[1:4]`.

Answer (score 2):

your not assigning line.strip to a variable e.g:

```
line_split = line.split()
vertices.append([[line_split[1],line_split[2],line_split[3]])
```

Another way would be:

```
for line in my_file:
    line_split = line.split()
    if line_split[0] == 'vertex':
        vertices.append([[line_split[1],line_split[2],line_split[3]])
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`list.split()` does not modify the list; it produces an entirely new list.

Assign the result of `line.split()` to line: `line = line.split()`

Then proceed as normal.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

This won't solve the problem though as you should still be pulling individual characters out of `line` (instead of blank space) due to the fact that strings act as lists of characters to begin with (see below).

```
text = "cat"
print(text[1])

>>> 'a'
```

I suspect that Python never gets past the `if line.startswith('vertex'):` condition. So as others have said, the core issue probably involves leading space or the file itself.

Also, if you're only reading the file, there's no need to include the access mode "r+". `my_file=open("test.stl")` works just as well and is more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what others have mentioned:

```
        vertices.append([[line[1],line[2],line[3]])
```

One too many left brackets before line[1], should be:

```
        vertices.append([line[1],line[2],line[3]])

print verticies
```

Your list is named vertices, not verticies.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:
`for line in my_file.readlines():`
readlines returns a list of all lines in the file.

You don't need to import sys in your case.

Comment: File objects are iterable, iterating over lines; `readlines()` just reads all the lines at once into memory.

Comment: `for line in file:` should always be enough for this kind of thing. `readlines()` is unnecessary.

Comment: BTW, being corrected on SO is sometimes more valuable than being upvoted: you learn something new!